# Add ignore SSL option into a request

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, curl, ssl-certificate

For generating the token I wrote this function:

```
  generateAuthorizationHeader() {
    const base64Token = Buffer.from(`${this.cfg.userEmail}:${this.cfg.userApiKey}`).toString('base64');
    return {
      Authorization: `Basic ${base64Token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
  }
```

the token returned is the correct one, it works fine. However, I need to ignore the SSL certificate too. This can be added in a curl call by adding `-k` in the request but I have no idea how to add this functionality into the function above.

Any suggestions about that?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your request object

```
rejectUnauthorized: false
```